# Chef: How to run a resource on notification only?

Tags: chef

I'd like to declare a resource that I want to run multiple times on notification and only on notification. How can I prevent the resource to run on its own after it is declared?

Is there some way to check if there is a notification present, so I can run something like "only_if :notified"?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `action :nothing` during declaration.

Answer (score 14):

Here is an example where my `execute` resource is only converged when my `directory` resource converges:

```
directory '/opt/foo' do
  action :create
  notifies :run, 'execute[custom command]', :immediately
end

execute 'custom command' do
  command 'echo foo'
  action :nothing
end
```

See https://docs.chef.io/chef/resources.html#notifications for more examples.